# Applying a colour change to a image as an overlay, keeping the orignal texture/shaders Javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, computer-vision, pixel

Performing "getimagedata" to replace the colour of the pixels in a image however, this completely removes the original pixels, want to achieve a overlay on the exisiting pixels to change the colour whilst keeping texture,shaders,and shape if possible.

```
var imageData = canvasContext.getImageData(video,0,0,canvasOutput.width,canvasOutput.height);
for (j = 0; j < imageData.data.length; j += 4){
            imageData.data[j] = rgb[0]; //red pixel
            imageData.data[j + 1] = rgb[1]; //green pixel
            imageData.data[j + 2] = rgb[2]; //blue pixel
            }
        canvasContext.putImageData(imageData,0,0)
```

pixels are being overwritten as opposed to being a colour overlay on the image.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution using OpenCV

```
cv.rectangle(overlayMat, point1, point2, [rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3]], -1); //img,(x,y), (x+width,y+height), scala 4 colour, fill
cv.addWeighted(overlayMat,alpha,vidMat,1 - alpha,0,vidMat);
```

applies a colour to the x,y position of point1, then the size is calculated using x + width, y + height in point 2, colour is based on RGBA Scalar array, -1 fills the entire area specified in point 2.

add weighted applies the coloured rect saved in another mat to the original mat using transparency of alpha values.